# how can i remove "/ ONLY" from "Rs1500/ONLY",using c#

Tags: c#, replace

```
string oldstring = textBox9.Text;
string newstring = oldstring.Remove(0, 2);
string o = newstring.Remove(4, 7);
```

Now, I want to get only `"1500"`,rest of the things to be removed.

How can I do this? Please help me.

Comment: You may want to start by turning off caps lock, otherwise you're going to have trouble writing your C# code later.

Comment: @BoltClock Perhaps some flavor of BASIC is more the OP's cup-of-tea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

```
string oldstring = textBox9.Text;
string newstring = oldstring.Replace("Rs","").Replace("/ONLY","");
```

This should give you only `1500`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
string newstring = Regex.Replace(oldstring, @"[^\d]", "");
```

It shall work.

Answer (score 1):

there are number of ways to do this.. you can use **Split()**  as below:

```
 string oldstring = "Rs1500/ONLY";
 string[] newstring = oldstring.Split('/');
 string o = newstring[0];
```

This will give you "RS 1500" as result.
And if you want to remove RS as well then just add the below code in last of the above code:

```
 string final = newstring[0].ToString().Replace("Rs","");
```

That's All

Comment: Am Already put the same answer !!

Comment: @RameshRajendran dude.. at that time i was writing this code... i have also seen now.. if you want then i can remove my answer...

Comment: Nope !  I have not explained for my code , Your answer have pretty explanation, So don't remove this !!

Comment: @RameshRajendran okz.. np.. actual matter is to resolve the problem...

Comment: @Henna don't forgot to accept the answer helped
 you..

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
    string ss = "Rs1500/ONLY";
    string[] newss = ss.Split('/');
    ss = newss[0].ToString().Replace("Rs","");//Or try string.Empty() for instead of ""
```

See this [demo code :](http://ideone.com/N4czow) with output

[image]